# How to overwrite beta versions in private gitlab NPM registry

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci, npm-publish

I am currently working with GitLab-CI and one problem that I have is that I need to use unique version names in my NPM registry. Now, while I really like this feature with NPM in the open world, in development when pipelines are run on development branches for features not released, this is somehow annoying since the registry gets filled up with trash pretty easily.

There are 2 ways I can think of to accomplish using the same version like 0.1.0-alpha again.

1. `npm unpublish`

   is not available in the GitLab registry at the moment
2. use curl and GitLab api to delete repository first

   This will probably the way I go if no one has a better solution, but I don't really like this approach as I don't want my pipeline and repositories being full with shell scripts that need maintaining.

Are there any more elegant solutions to this problem?

Comment: How is the registry getting full of trash? The recommended ways to have experimental packages is either publishing a version like v1.2.3-alpha.1 or v0.0.0-experimental.{git hash} to a separate nom publish channel and keeping them available forever, or build using `npm pack` to produce temporary packages